# Elasticsearch - equivalent of LEFT JOIN

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 20,000,000 line items in Elasticsearch that I am happily searching (it's working amazingly well).

There is an added dimension though that I don't know how to solve:

A user can "buy" those items (in batches of 1,000 to 100,000) and I need my search to only return the items that they have not previously "bought". I'd solve this with a LEFT JOIN in SQL.

I could add a boughtBy[] field to each item, but then I would need to update lots of documents every time a user buys. Feels kind of wrong?

Comment: And how is `they have not previously "bought"` defined in your cluster?

Comment: "bought" is not defined yet - that is kind of the question, but essentially it is just a set of ids. boughtBy[] could be a set of user ids.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join query in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611049/join-query-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elasticsearch uses Lucene which supports blockjoin. In Elasticsearch that is [Parent-Child Relationships](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html). It gives you a join but it also comes with limitations (it's no longer possible to arbitrarily distribute documents across nodes, memory requirements can explode in certain scenarios).

Elasticsearch documentation gives you [a nice overview of the relationship modelling options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html).

If you need deep joins, more complex relationships, etc., you might consider looking into the [SIREn plugin](http://siren.solutions/siren/overview/).

*(disclaimer: I currently work for the company that develops SIREn)*