# How to perform JOIN operation in elasticsearch

Tags: join, elasticsearch, querydsl

How to perform JOIN operation in elasticsearch on the same index?

This is the set of field fow each documents:

```
      "@version": "1",
      "@timestamp": "2016-04-26T15:56:05.379Z",
      "phone": "..."
      "path": "...",
      "host": "...",
      "type": "...",
      "clientip": "...",
      "ident": "-",
      "auth": "-",
      "timestamp": "...",
      "verb": "...",
      "uripath": "...",
      "httpversion": "1.1",
      "response": "200",
      "bytes": "515",
      "timetaken": "383",
      "event_type": "type1"
    }
```

If I would to get the **phone** of documents that have (**event_type** of *type1*, **timestamp** between *date1* and *date2*) and (**event_type** of *type2*, **timestamp** between *date3* and *date4*)

In mysql thinking would be a join between two views

Comment: From the docs it says that "dis_max" function could be used here. Did you come accross this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join query in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611049/join-query-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0):

I might not be the most optimized request, but it worked:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "timestamp ": {
                        "lte": date1,
                        "gte": date2
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "event_type ": "type1"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "timestamp ": {
                        "lte": date3,
                        "gte": date4
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "event_type ": "type2"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It will return all the documents that have event_type of type1, timestamp between date1 and date2 and all the documents that have event_type of type2, timestamp between date3 and date4.

The `bool should` will return all the documents that respect any of its part.

Comment: This is like  (event_type of type1, timestamp between date1 and date2) OR (event_type of type2, timestamp between date3 and date4)

Comment: @M_M I'll add details, but if you tested it, I would like to have details.

Comment: @M_M Yes, it's the documents that have (event_type of type1, timestamp between date1 and date2) OR (event_type of type2, timestamp between date3 and date4), but with AND, you won't have any results, no?

Comment: If they are performed by the same user? it' like you want to add a where close, something like this

Comment: `select id from 
(select * from A where event_type = type1, date1 < timestamp < date2) 
join 
(select * from B where event_type = type2, date3 < timestamp < date4) 
on a.user = b.user`

Comment: @M_M I'm pretty sure that's not possible with ES.