# Count by keyword in several indexes in ElasticSearch 6

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm relatively new to ElasticSearch so I may be asking something silly. Anyway, here's my use case:

We want to store all the messaging going on in our Booking Engine, and as a plus, see if we can get some nice data out of it.

Basically we would store 5 different documents in as many indexes:

- `SessionOpen Response`, with a `sessionId` and all the navigation data (`DNS`, `country`, `ip`, etc.).
- `Availability Request/ Response`, with the same `sessionId` as
  keyword.
- `Booking Request/ Response`, with the same `sessionId` as
  keyword.

My question is, would it be possible to filter the `sessionId`'s by its navigation data (for example, `country`), and then count the number of `Availability Requests` / `Booking` for these filtered sessionId's?

The idea is to get something like this:

```
╔═════════╦════════════════╦══════════╗
║ Country ║ Requests       ║ Bookings ║
╠═════════╬════════════════╬══════════╣
║ Spain   ║            300 ║        5 ║
║ Germany ║            650 ║        9 ║
║ France  ║            250 ║        3 ║
╚═════════╩════════════════╩══════════╝
```

I've looked into it [quite a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611049/join-query-in-elasticsearch#22633775) and it [seems impossible](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) to search in several indexes at once, but maybe I'm just storing the data in the wrong way. I could (for example), store all the navigation data in every document and then query those, but it seems like it could be wasting space and be heavy on indexation as well.

Since ElasticSearch [removed mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) and encourages one document per index, I don't see how to get this kind of data easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a problem with making multiple requests you could:

first query `SessionOpen Response` to get the `sessionIds` by whatever navigation data.

Then with the result of `sessionIds` you could make a query (maybe Count API) to `Availability Requests` index.

Using the `sessionIds` you could query any index you have and build up the final object you need.

Comment: Let's say I retrieve 10.000 sessionId's from the first request. How do I send these to the second query to count? Since they are website sessions, those numbers are possible.

Comment: You need to use aggregations which will be done for each sessionId. The results will be returned in your one query but with a bucket result per sessionId.