# calcite elasticsearch adapter efficient join

Tags: elasticsearch, join, apache-calcite

What is the proper way to implement JOIN rewrite to allow query to be fed with results of subquery? 
For example:

```
SELECT state  FROM zips_view WHERE j IN (select j from people_view)
```

This query gets rewritten to SemiJoin which executes table scan inner query (select agains _people_view_ as expected) then again table scan for outer query (select against _zips_view_). The second scan can be replaced with filtered query e.g.

```
SELECT state FROM zips_iew WHERE j IN (1,2,3,4)
```

What's the proper way to implement a "two phase" JOIN which takes results of subquery and adds them to outer query as filter/condition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join query in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611049/join-query-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JDBC connector here, and for your desired query:

```
SELECT state FROM zips_iew WHERE j IN (1,2,3,4)
```

it generates this relational algebra:

```
LogicalProject(state=[$0])
  LogicalFilter(condition=[OR(=($0, 1), =($0, 2), =($0, 3), =($0, 4))])
    JdbcTableScan(table=[[zips_iew, state]])
```

You should start by writing rules that transform your original relational algebra (with SemiJoin) and work your way down to get the relational algebra that looks like above.