# Performing joins on indices in flat file storage systems

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, join, bigdata, flat-file

To calculate the metrics which is equivalent to SQL Query below in Elasticsearch or any other similar flat file storage systems.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT required_column_name)
FROM table_1 A
INNER JOIN table_1 B ON A.matching_column_name = B.matching_column_name
WHERE A.distinguishing_column_name = 'distinguishing_value_A'
  AND B.distinguishing_column_name = 'distinguishing_value_B';
```

Reference - http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-self-join/.

I would like to know if there exists such a possibility for joining indices in Elasticsearch. After which, I would like to calculate the proportion of the matching column between the two classes. For example, 30 percent of elements are in common between class A and class B.

**Scenario:** Let us consider there are y documents in an index which has only two fields in each of them. If the total number of unique values of first and second field is m and n, then there can be m*n unique combinations. The first field has one of values from ("Class_1", "Class_2", "Class_3"). The second field has values which are some sort of IDs of alphanumeric values and this value might repeat (consider encrypted email ID for example). I would like to know the IDs in common between Class_1 and Class_2, Class_1 and Class_3, Class_2 and Class_3 and among all three three together.

[The numbered regions on this image is the expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsfwU.jpg)

The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) and [Elasticsearch forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-fetch-data-from-multiple-index-using-join-like-sql/106131) mentions that there are no options for joins. Indeed, we can bind Elasticsearch to powerful platforms like Python, Java, etc., using APIs and perform the required operation in the programming environment. Since it is a not efficient in terms of performance and it does not make the complete use of Map Reduce, is there any work around for this requirement to perform in the Storage environment itself.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. Remove those extra parentheses to make code clearer - for all... I.e. simply `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT required_column_name)`.

Comment: The changes have been made as suggested.

Comment: SQL DBMSs are not "flat file storage systems". Find out what a DBMS is & what a relational DBMS is. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Ask one question per post. This is 2--how to do joins & related operations & how to code your specific problem in it. Get an answer to the 1st then show your work trying to code the 2nd. Re the 1st: (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Re the 2nd: Determine a system to code in. Then code. Then if you are stuck: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join query in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611049/join-query-in-elasticsearch)